# Conditional Moq Return value using lambda

Tags: unit-testing, lambda, moq

Is it possible to return different results based on the input, like in

```
MoqSecurityAdminHelper.Setup(x => x.GetAllQuestions(It.IsAny<Boolean>()))
    .Returns(new Dictionary<String, String>
    {
        {"Key1", "Value1"},
        {"Key2", "Value2"}
    });
```

but if the argument is true return one result, if false... another.

Or is the only way to do it having 2 separate setups?

Thanks

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
MoqSecurityAdminHelper.Setup(x => x.GetAllQuestions(It.IsAny<Boolean>()))
                      .Returns((bool param) => param ? 
                                          someResult : 
                                          someOtherResult );
```

Answer (score 1):

If the param is defined before you can also use this

```
MoqSecurityAdminHelper.Setup(x => x.GetAllQuestions(It.IsAny<Boolean>()))
                      .Returns(param ? result : otherResult);
```